# output redirection in UNIX

Tags: unix, redirect

I am a beginner in UNIX. I am finding some difficulty in input/output redirection.

1. `ls -l >temp`

   `cat temp`

   Here why temp file is shown in the list and moreover, it is showing 0 characters.
2. `wc temp >temp`

   `cat temp`

   here output is `0 0 0 temp`.
   Why lines, words, characters are 0.

Please help me to undestand this concept.

Comment: No, it's not homework.  
I am learning The Unix Programming Environment by Kernighan and Pike and they are exercise questions which I wasn't getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because `ls` reads all the names and sorts them before printing anything, and because the output file is created before the command is executed, at the time when `ls` checks the size of `temp`, it is empty, so it shows up in the list as an empty file.
2. When `wc` reads the file, it is empty, so it reports 0 characters in 0 words on 0 lines, and writes this information into the file after it has finished reading the empty file.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks. But after ls command, temp is not empty. Right?  
so why wc reads it as empty file?

Comment: Because when you do `wc temp >temp`, the '>temp' is handled before the command is executed, and that empties the file.  Contrast with `wc temp >>temp` which appends.

Answer (score 3):

When you pipe the output to a file, that file is created, the command is run (so ls lists it as an empty file, and wc counts the characters in the empty file), then the output is added to the file.

… in that order.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write and read from the same file at the same time.

So:

```
wc file > file # NOT WORKING
# but this works:
wc file > file.stats 
mv file.stats file # if you want that
```